# Possibility for merging side by side multiple excel files

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to merge the excel files side by side. Suppose I have stored two separate Excel files in Drive C, named A and B For example File A is like this:

```html
BB LL KO PO
A C D A
A C D A
A C D A
A C D A
```

File B is like:

```html
WW YY ZZ XX
Q C D Z
Q C D Z
Q C D Z
Q C D Z
```

I need to have this:

```html
BB LL KO PO WW YY ZZ XX
A C D A Q C D Z
A C D A Q C D Z
A C D A Q C D Z
A C D A Q C D Z
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to append file B to file A, or create new file with merged these two files? And what is the range of the table? Does it start in A1 cell in every file?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the tables start in cell A1 (the top-left cell of the table) and that you have 4x4 tables (you can easily generalise that behaviour). You have to run this code in a worksheet, where you want the data to be merged. You have to also specify the paths to the files in the code and make sure that the names of the sheets are correct.

```
Sub merge()
Dim actWb, wb As Workbook
Dim i, j As Integer
'set workbooks, so you can switch between them during the program
Set actWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
'here you also open workbook you want to copy data from
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("PATH TO THE FILE")
'loop through the range you want to copy
For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 4
        actWb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j).Value =     wb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
'close the workbook
wb.Close
'repeat above for the other workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("PATH TO THE OTHER FILE")

For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 4
        actWb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j + 4).Value =     wb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i
wb.Close

End Sub
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You have to copy full path in `THE PATH TO THE FILE` place. Simpliest way to obtain desired path is to open properties of the excel file, copy the path from there and put additional "\filename/xlsx".

Comment: I got this error: actWb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j).Value =     wb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j).Value. Subscript out of range

Comment: Make sure that sheet name is correct. Then try first looping for i = 1 to 1 and for j = 1 to 1. If that works, you can play with it and change the ranges. Btw, it works on my computer.

Comment: Sheet names are correct. When I changed the fist loop (for i = 1 to 1 and for j = 1 to 1) , i got error Run Time error 9, subscript out of range. I do not know how to fix it. can you help me.

Comment: Michał Turczyn, Any help?

Comment: You must use wrong sheets names, read this please:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519(v=vs.60).aspx

Keep in mind that you have new worksheet in `actWb`, so you have to use `Sheet1` name, I guess.

UPDATE: I just realized - I typed `Sheets1` name just for example, actual default name is `Sheet1`. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I have changed sheets1 to sheet1. I used or i = 1 to 1 and for j = 1 to 1), I o not get an error, but I did not get the emerged file properly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Now, change the ranges: the `row` number should be the number of rows that you have, then you write `i = 1 To  row` instead `i =1 To 1`, then determine number of columns: `col` and write `j = 1 To col` instead of `j = 1 To 1`. The last thing to change is the line `actWb.Sheets("Sheets1").Cells(i, j + 4)` - change `4` to number of columns you have in your first file.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `Function` that takes care to store cells values of a given worksheet of a given workbook in a `Variant` variable, like the following one:

```
Function GetWBValues(fullFileName As String, shtName As String, values As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    With Workbooks.Open(fullFileName).Worksheets(shtName) '<--| try opening passed file and accessing its passed sheet name
        values = .UsedRange.Value
        .Parent.Close False '<--| close just opened workbook without saving any changes
    End With
    GetWBValues = True '<--| set function return value to 'True' to signal calling sub that values has been successfully read
ExitFunction:
End Function
```

to be exploited by some "main" calling code like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub merge()
    Dim values As Variant

    If GetWBValues("C:\Desktop\......\File1.xlsx", "Sheet1", values) Then
        Cells.Resize(UBound(values, 1), UBound(values, 2)).Value = values
    End If

    If GetWBValues("C:\Desktop\......\File2.xlsx", "Sheet4", values) Then
        With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            .Columns(.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(UBound(values, 1), UBound(values, 2)).Value = values
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you User3598756- I have different Excel files. does not work for me. can you help more

Comment: you must provide as many details as possibile and define what _"does not work"_ mean...

Comment: I am using table table 2.  If GetWBValues("C:\Desktop\......\File2.xlsx", "Sheet4", values). sub or function not defined. any help uUser3598756

Comment: You have to put GetWBValues() function code in any module of your VBA project (even in the same module of your main sub)